# Excel Regex Add 2 spaces instead of one

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm using the below function in Excel to split the caps of some data. How can I adapt it to add 2 spaces between words e.g `Mike  Jones` rather than just one as it does now. Simple answer I'm sure but RegEx baffles me at the best of times.

```
Function SplitCaps(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
    SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2")
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very very simple: add an extra space between the 2 regex groups $1 and $2

```
SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1  $2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is

```
    ([a-zA-Z]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add '\s'? This should be a comment but I cant comment as of now. 
try: 
You can add extra white space using \s:

```
    SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1\s\s$2")
```